# C#: ObservableCollection - why no generic "CollectionChanged" event?

Tags: c#, events, generics, language-design

This is not so much a question, and more something that struck me as odd: the `ObservableCollection` class is generic, but the `CollectionChanged` event that it raises when changed to the collection occur is not. That means within the event handler, you have to cast all the objects in the `NewItems`/`OldItems` collections you get from the event args object to the proper item type yourself.

But shouldn't it have been simply possible to make that event generic? Something like

```
public virtual event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler<T> CollectionChanged;
```

with

```
public delegate void NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs<T> e);
```

and then

```
public class NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs<T> {
    // ...
    public IList<T> NewItems { get; }
    public IList<T> OldItems { get; }
```

After all, the type parameter `T` is already determined by the declaration of the `ObservableCollection` in question, which means you should never be able to add any objects that are not of type `T` (or compatible to it) to the collection anyway. So all of this should be perfectly type safe, and save us the trouble of having to cast the objects inside the event handler into whatever type we know they should have anyway.

Is there a reason for not doing it this way that I am missing? I.e. is this a conscious design desicion, or just an oversight?

Comment: If i recall correctly (but i very well might be wrong) this had something to do with WPF that was not able to work with generics but needed to know how to listen to collection changes (ObservableCollection is introduced for the sake of WPF basically so that makes sense)

Answer (score -2):

The `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface, along with `INotifyPropertyChanged`, were designed exclusively for use by the WPF framework. Since WPF is loosely typed, I'm guessing that generics weren't part of that design. I don't think `INotifyCollectionChanged` was designed to be consumed directly. Whereas, `ObservableCollection<T>` is designed to be consumed by C# code, which is strongly typed, therefore generics featured in the design.

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` was introduced in .NET 2.0 so it most certainly wasn't designed exclusively for WPF.

Comment: INotiftPropertyChanged was introduced along side IErrorInfo for data binding in original windows forms. The binding source only deals with the type 'Object'.

Comment: ObservableCollection<T> implements INotifyCollectionChanged along with INotifyPropertyChanged,